# Is it possible to express $(1+i)^{4}$ in complex form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Use DeMoivre’s theorem to find $z^{4}$, if $z =1 + i$. Express your answer in complex form.

**a.** $180^{\circ}$

**b.** $16$

**c.** $-8$

**d.** $-16$

**e.** None of these

---

The correct answer is "None of these". And I would like to know whether the answer is possible to express in complex form?

My final result is $4 ~\text{cis} \ 45^{\circ}$ and to express it in complex form, I think that I will need to insert $i$. So, I have no idea to express it in complex form. Or, is it possible? Or, what is complex form?

Comment: In complex for $4\operatorname{cis} 45^\circ$ would be $4(\cos 45 + i \sin 45) = 4\frac {\sqrt 2}2 + i4\frac {\sqrt 2}2= 2\sqrt 2 + i 2 \sqrt 2$.  But that is not the right answer.  You made an error.  Your (second to final) result should have been $4\operatorname{cis} 180^\circ$.  Which in complex form is $4(\cos 180 + i\sin 180) = -4 + 0*i = -4$.

Comment: awh, I forget what cis meant. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: A technique worth knowing: [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) gives $z^4=(z^2)^2=(2i)^2=-4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $1 + 1i = 1+i$.

Method 1 (not DeMoivre):  $(1+i)^4 = 1^4 + 4*1^3*i + 6*1^2*i^2 + 4*1*i^3 + i^4$

Now $i^1 = 1$.  And $i^2 =-1$ and $i^3 = i^2* i = (-1)*i = -i$ and $i^4 = i^3*i = (-i)*i = (-1)*i*i=(-1)*i^2 = (-1)*(-1) = 1$.  Or $i^4 = (i^2)^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$.

So  $(1+i)^4 = 1^4 + 4*1^3*i + 6*1^2*i^2 + 4*1*i^3 + i^4=$

$1 + 4i -6 - 4i + 1= (1-6+1)+(4i-4i) = -4 + 0 = -4$.

And in complex form that is $-4 + 0i$.

Method 2 (DeMoivre):

$1+ i = \sqrt {2} (\frac {\sqrt 2}2 + i \frac {\sqrt 2}2)=$

$\sqrt{2}(\cos 45^\circ +i \sin 45^\circ)=$

$\sqrt{2} \operatorname{cis} (45^\circ)$.

So $(1+i)^4 = (\sqrt 2)^4 \operatorname{cis}(4*45^\circ)$

$4\operatorname{cis}(180^\circ)= $

$4(\cos 180 + i \sin 180) =$

$4(-1 + 0*i) = $

$-4 + 0i$.

Which is equal to $-4$.

Comments.  1) You don't put an $i$ in the $\operatorname{cis}$ form because $\operatorname{cis}$ *is* a complex number.  By *definition*  $k\operatorname{cis}(angle) = k(\cos angle + i \sin angle) = k\cos angle + (k\sin angle)i = x  + yi$ where $x = k\cos angle, y=k\sin angle$.

Notice also that as long as $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ there will *ALWAYS* be and angle $\theta$ and a positive real number $k$ so that $x = k\cos \theta, y = k\sin \theta$.  *ALWAYS*.  If for example:  $x = 5$ and $y = 7$ then $k=\sqrt{5^2 + 7^2}=\sqrt{89}$ then $x = k*\frac 5{\sqrt{89}}, y = k\frac 7{\sqrt{89}}$ and if $\cos \theta = \frac 5{\sqrt{89}}$ and $\sin\theta = \frac 7{\sqrt{89}}$ then $\theta = \arctan \frac {\frac 5{\sqrt{89}}}{\frac 7{\sqrt{89}}}=\arctan\frac 57$ and $k= \sqrt{89}$ and $\theta = \arctan\frac 57$ and $x = k\cos \theta; y=k\sin \theta$.

Comment 2)  The rule is $(r\operatorname{cis} \theta)^k= r^k\operatorname{cis} (k \cdot \theta)$.  You didn't multiply your angle by $4$.

Comment 3).  $\operatorname{cis}$ is just notation short hand for $\cos x + i \sin x$.  It doesn't *mean* anything in itself.

Comment 4).  You should get used to writing $\operatorname{cis}(angle)$ as $e^{i\cdot angle}$.

Comment 5).  You should get used to using radian rather than angle based on $360$ degrees.  $45^\circ = \frac {\pi}4$.

The final answer should be $(1+i)^4 = (\frac {\sqrt 2}2 e^{i\frac \pi 4})^4 =(\frac {\sqrt 2}2)^4 e^{i\frac pi 4\cdot 4}= 4e^{-i\pi }=4*(-1) = -4$.

(Remember Eulers Formula?  $e^{\pi i} =-1$?  That... comes into play.  $45^0\times 4 = 180^\circ = \pi$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+i)^4=\left ( \sqrt{2} \operatorname{cis}(45^\circ) \right )^4 = (\sqrt{2})^4 \operatorname{cis}(4 \cdot 45^\circ)=-4.$$

So basically the error in your solution was forgetting to take into account the change in the phase. You got the magnitude correct and thus avoided walking into the trap that they laid for you with answer d.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1+i=\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt2}i\right)=\sqrt2\operatorname{cis}(45^\circ)$,$$(1+i)^4=\sqrt2^4\operatorname{cis}(180^\circ)=4\times(-1)=-4+0\times i.$$

Comment: If you were not required to "use DeMoivre’s theorem" it is easy to calculate that (1+ i)^2= 1^2+ 2(1)(i)+ i^2= 1+ 2i- 1= 2i.  And that (1+ i)^4= (2i)^2= -4.

Comment: @user247327 Sure!

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem and expanding the summation:

$$\left(1+i\right)^4=\sum _{i=0}^4\binom{4}{i}\cdot \:1^{\left(4-i\right)}i^i=1+4i-6-4i+1=-4$$